# This is supposed to be vulnerable to SQL injection but I can't really see how. Is it really that bad?

Tags: php, sql-injection

See bellow php code that takes a url param, queries a db and then returns a string:

```
$inpt = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9" . '' . "]", "", $_GET['param']);
$rtrn    = $core_db->Execute("Select col1, col2, col3 from table where id=?", array(
    $inpt
));
if ($rtrn->EOF) {
    echo 'N/A';
} else {
    echo '<span style="color:#333333; font-size: 10px;">' . decode_map($rtrn->fields[0]) . ', X:' . $rtrn->fields[1] . ' Y:' . $rtrn->fields[2] . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Who said it was vulnerable? And why do you think it is not vulnerable?

Comment: `select X from table where id = user supplied input` is generally bad design.

Comment: Bit of a side note, but `ereg_replace` has been deprecated for almost 14 years, how old is your PHP!? Probably the server itself is full of known vulnerabilities, if it's that out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know all the details of PHP and you're doing something weird with the `''` in the middle of that regex, but in general if you aren't removing spaces, that's definitely exploitable. Even without parentheses or semicolons (which would allow much greater SQLi flexibility), an attacker could add clauses to your WHERE expression, such as `Select col1, col2, col3 from table where id=1 OR secret IS NOT NULL` or similar silliness. They could also return the whole table (`... where id=1 OR TRUE`) or inject potentially-expensive operations like joins. You'd be better off if the parameter were a string and was in quotes (and your regex filtered out all the ways to escape the quotes), but even that isn't a *great* approach. In your current code, if spaces are in fact disallowed, you MIGHT be OK (I don't think there's a way to terminate a value in SQL working only with the alphanumeric character set, so an attacker could pass some wild values for `id` but nothing else) but it's a needlessly reckless way to do DB queries.

Just use any form of parameterized query, including possibly a prepared statement or stored procedure. Inherent safety against SQL injection, often performs faster, often includes type safety, potentially lets you use least-privileged connections... it's much better.

Comment: If you don’t 100% build the text of the query yourself, then it is vulnerable. And if you ask “is it vulnerable” then the answer is “yes”.